# Virtualenv Permission denied when trying python setup.py install

Tags: software-installation, permissions, python, python3, pip

I want to use `virtualenv` with Python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04. Specifically, I'm using Python 3.6.6 and virtualenv 16.0.0.

1. I installed virtualenv with `sudo` as suggested [in the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504231/2745116): `sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv`
2. I created a new virtualenv using `python3 -m virtualenv venv`. And activated it as usual: `source venv/bin/activate`.
3. When I try to install my Python project with `python setup.py install` I get the following error message:

```
    running install
    running bdist_egg
    running egg_info
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

If I use `sudo` to create the virtualenv in step 2, then I get a different error message in step 3:

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/stefan/git-repos/tng-sdk-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-3769.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /home/stefan/git-repos/tng-sdk-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

I've been googling and trying stuff for hours now and I can't get it to work properly. It seems like whatever I try leads to more, new errors... Any ideas?

Well, `sudo python setup.py install` works inside the virtualenv, but this can't be the solution.

Comment: you have python3.6, try `python3 setup.py install`

Comment: Same error message. Since I installed the virtualenv with `python3`, `python --version` gives me 3.6.6 inside the virtualenv. So there shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: try to `sudo chmod 755 /home/stefan/git-repos/tng-sdk-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` and run `python3 setup.py install` again

Comment: Same error message (2nd one): `error: can't create or remove files in install directory`

Comment: I even tried reinstalling `python3` and `python3-pip`. But without success.

Comment: it's not about python installation, you need Python interpreter to your project with `virtualenv -p python3.6 /home/stefan/git-repos/tng-sdk-project/`

Answer (score 1):

Most probably used `sudo` for some instructions that create some folder with root ownership.

1. Deactivate the virtual env.
2. Try fix owner recursively:

   ```
   sudo chown -R stefan:stefan /home/stefan/git-repos/tng-sdk-project/
   ```
3. Activate virtual env and test it.